# c# chromedriver read logs and clear them

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, console.log

I am doing e2e testing using chrome-driver and selenium. As part of testing each page, I want to check console.logs to see if there are any errors and then before moving on to a new page, I want to clear the console logs.

I can read logs using

```
  _driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser).ToList();
```

Is it possible to clear the console logs??

Comment: Have you tried simply:  `_driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog("");`?

Comment: @Brian how will that clear logs??

Comment: I am not sure.  We don't use the Selenium loggers here at work.  I just did some digging via Google and [this](https://gist.github.com/sachinArya/1537dbfa4f29b49df565), was what I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple one, here's the code (self explanatory)

```
    var jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.ExecuteScript("console.clear()");
```